# Calling main Variable from a different class

Tags: java, variables, program-entry-point

Hi I'm relatively new to Java but I think I'm starting to get somewhat of a hang of it. Anyway, I was wondering if it's at all possible to access a variable declared in the main method (or class if that's easier) from a completely different class and if so how? For example I've programmed a simple simulation of The Game of Life and I want to easily be able to change the size of my grid by changing one variable. However this variable needs to change not only functional grid that the computer sees but also the GUI grid. Since the GUI grid isn't in the main class file I don't know how to access the variable. Any suggestions?

//Thanks, Ivar

Comment: You should maybe learn about OOP and encapsulation before starting out gui programming. [The Java Tutorials - OOP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/)

Comment: This is one of the basics of programming in Java (and many other languages) called scoping. Short answer: no. Longer, more useful answer: head over to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html, read through them, and after that hour you'll be much better off for playing with Java.

Comment: Instead of figuring out how to get the GUI grid class to access a variable in the main program, it might be better to add a way to get the main program to tell the GUI grid class to change the size.  This starts getting into learning the concepts behind OOP, so I think @ifLoop's suggestion is a great one.

Comment: A variable declared locally inside a method can never be changed from outside.  It doesn't even make sense to think about doing it since there is no single instance of that variable.  Rather, one is created each time the function is called.  (Might be more than one at a time, or zero.)

Comment: That was fast and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Advice: your best bet would be to get a textbook on Java and OO programming.  You aren't likely to learn this stuff properly by just trying to write programs.

This applies to anyone else who is looking for answers to questions like this.

---

> Anyway, I was wondering if it's at all possible to access a variable declared in the main method (or class if that's easier) from a completely different class and if so how?

A variable declared in the `main` method is a local variable, and it cannot be accessed from anywhere else<sup>1</sup>.

A variable can be declared as in the class (say `C`) that contains the `main` method.

- An instance variable (aka a field) can be accessed from another class (modulo the visibility rules ... see below) provided you have created an instance of `C`.
- A static variable doesn't require an instance of `C` ... but the flipside is that the variable has only one instance.

The visibility rules say whether or not another class is permitted to access a variable (or method).  A `private` field is not visible at all.  A `public` field is visible to every class.  The `protected` and package private visibilities are between no visibility and full visibility.

It is permitted to declare all of your fields as `public` so that everything can see and (typically) modify the state.  However it is a bad idea, because it breaks down the "abstraction boundaries" that are need to main large-scale OO program understandable and maintainable.

---

<sup>1 - This is not strictly true.  A method's local variables are potentially in-scope and visible to nested classes or lambdas that are declared within the method.  However, said variables must be `final` or effectively final (depending on Java version).  Besides, I doubt that this will be the right solution for a first-steps programmming exercise ...</sup>